# Access superclass objects from subclass

Tags: python-3.x, subclass, super

I am still new to classes, and I am struggling a bit bit a subclass I am trying to implement.

So I have my `Nitin` class as such:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Nitin(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.session = requests.session()
        self.urls = {'base': 'http://nitinproductions.com/models/', 'models': 'http://nitinproductions.com/models/models.php'}

    def login(self):
        self.session.auth = (self.username, self.password)
        r = self.session.get(self.urls['models'])
        return self.session
```

This step is fine, as I can log in and `self.session` is updates in the `login()` function. Now I have a `Model` subclass, which should have access to the original `Nitin.session`.

```
class Model(Nitin):
    def __init__(self, nitin, model):
        super(Model, self).__init__(nitin)
        self.model = model
        self.nitin = nitin


    def media(self):
        r = self.nitin.session.get(self.model)
        print(r.status_code)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        for table in soup.find('div', {'id': 'photobar'}).findAll('table'):
            print(table)
```

I am attempting to do this in my main code as follows:

```
# Imports all Nitin classes
from src import *

# Initialize Nitin object
ripper = Nitin(username='aaaa', password='bbb')
# Initialize session with u/p
ripper.login()

# Initialize Model by passing the Nitin object to it, as well as a link
model = Model(nitin=ripper, model='http://nitinproductions.com/models/lexxiliegh/lexxiliegh.php')
```

But this raises the following exception:

```
    model = Model(nitin=ripper, model='http://nitinproductions.com/models/lexxiliegh/lexxiliegh.php')
  File "/home/redact/git/redact/src/Nitin.py", line 32, in __init__
    super(Model, self).__init__(nitin)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'
```

I think I am understanding the classes worng. I would actually like to do the following:

```
rippper = Nitin(username='aaaa', password='bbbb)
rippper.login()
rippper.Model.media()
```

But I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but the error is caused be the fact that `Model` **extends** `Nitin` in addition to containing it. The line that makes this happen is

```
class Model(Nitin):
```

Since `Model` also contains a reference to a `Nitin` object, I suspect that you really want something like

```
class Model(object):
```

The line `super(Model, self).__init__(nitin)` attempts to call the constructor of the superclass. In this case, `Nitin.__init__` is being called with one argument (`nitin`), instead of the required username and password.

I suggest that you have `Model` extend `object` and remove any calls to `super(...).__init__` entirely in that case.

Extending a class means having all of its attributes and functionality available to the extending class without having to re-implement the same code. Your code looks like it just needs a reference to a `Nitin` instance (which you are doing correctly), not to extend it (which you are doing, but incorrectly).

To answer your question about how to reference a `Model` from a `Nitin`: you can initialize a model within `Nitin.__init__` using `self` as the `Nitin` reference in the call to `Model.__init__`. Your `Nitin.__init__` would look something like this:

```
def __init__(self, username, password, model_url):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.session = requests.session()
    self.urls = {'base': 'http://nitinproductions.com/models/', 'models': 'http://nitinproductions.com/models/models.php'}
    self.model = Model(self, model_url)
```

You could then execute exactly the code you want, with the only differences being that you would pass the model URL to the `Nitin` constructor as well as the fact that the `model` attribute is lowercase:

```
rippper = Nitin(username='aaaa', password='bbbb', model_url='http://nitinproductions.com/models/lexxiliegh/lexxiliegh.php')
rippper.login()
rippper.model.media()
```

Comment: After making the changes you suggested it works, but I'd like to know if there is a way to call the `Model` class like `Nitin.Model.some_function_from_Model()` after I have initialised `Nitin`. Where `Nitin` gets initialialised and the session created, and I can just continue working with `Model`.

Comment: @ou_snaaksie. Then just initialize `self.model` in `Nitin.__init__`. You can pass `self` to `Model.__init__` just like you are doing in the external code now.

Comment: I don't quite understand.. sorry. Would you mind updating your answer with what you just said? The classes are confusing me

Comment: @ou_snaaksie. Just did.